# "If folder isn't empty"

Tags: applescript

I'm making a simple Applescript to check if the trash has an item, and if so, ask to empty it. I'm having trouble with checking if the trash is empty or not, though. Here's what I have:

`set trashcontents to text returned of (do shell script "ls ~/.Trash")`.

This returns `error "Can’t get text returned of \"untitled folder\"." number -1728 from text returned of "untitled folder"` when "untitled folder" is in the trash, and `error "Can’t get text returned of \"\"." number -1728 from text returned of ""` when it's empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `text returned` is for user dialogs only. The `do shell script` command simply returns the text that is printed to stout by that shell script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's even simpler actually:

```
do shell script "ls ~/.Trash"
set trashcontents to result
```

`result` will be equal to `""` (empty string) when the Trash is empty.

But, unless you want to empty the Trash depending on whether it contains particular items (in your question, it sounds like "if it's not empty, empty it"), there's no need to check if it's empty... The Finder command to empty the Trash will have no effect anyway if there's nothing in it:

```
tell application "Finder" to empty the trash
```

Comment: I'm making it check if the trash is empty every 30 minutes, and if it has an item, ask to empty (so nothing important is deleted, but it stays empty otherwise). But the `set trashcontents to result` helped, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
set trashcontents to quoted form of (do shell script "ls ~/.Trash")
```